# Sistema con más incógnitas que ecuaciones

Tags: matemáticas, matlab

Mi problema esta vez es que estoy trabajando un sistema con más incógnitas (4) que ecuaciones (2), y no sé cómo salir al paso de esta situación. Mi sistema es el siguiente:

```
bc*(L+ms)=A
L*bv=B
```

donde A y B son conocidos para nosotros y sabemos que A < B; mientras que ms, L, bc, bv son las incógnitas cuyo valor deseamos conocer.

Podéis tomar como ejemplo:

```
A = 48792
B = 64800
```

Según la teoría, debería ofrecer dos valores conocidos a dos de las incógnitas e intentar despejar las otras dos a partir de éstos. Sin embargo, como necesito hacer ésto para varios valores conocidos de A y B, sería mucho más sencillo contar con un procedimiento para hacer ésto vía MATLAB.

Tengo algunas ideas orientativas sobre qué resultados espero conseguir. **Todos las incógnitas deberían tener valores naturales** (supongo que también podría dar por bueno un valor real tan próximo a un número natural que pudiera ser aproximado como tal). Aparte, sería deseable que **el valor de L fuera mucho mayor que el del resto de las incógnitas**.

¿Sabéis si existe alguna solución al respecto?

Si no existiera (que ojalá que sí...) pienso que otra opción interesante sería indagar todos los valores por los que A o B podrían ser divisibles e intentar buscar a mano las combinaciones que más me convengan.

¡Muchas gracias de antemano, y un saludo!

## Editado (13/04/17):

He iniciado un pequeño programa para buscar los divisores de 48792 y de 64800 y los resultados parecen bastante poco alentadores...

DIVISORES DE 48792 (32)

1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 12, 19, 24, 38, 57, 76, 107, 114, 152, 214, 228, 321, 428, 456, 642, 856, 1284, 2033, 2568, 4066, 6099,
8132, 12198, 16264, 24396, 48792

DIVISORES DE 64800 (90)

1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 12, 15, 16, 18, 20, 24, 25, 27, 30, 32, 36, 40, 45, 48, 50, 54, 60, 72, 75, 80, 81, 90, 96,
100, 108, 120, 135, 144, 150, 160, 162, 180, 200, 216, 225, 240, 270, 288, 300, 324, 360, 400, 405, 432, 450, 480, 540,
600, 648, 675, 720, 800, 810, 864, 900, 1080, 1200, 1296, 1350, 1440, 1620, 1800, 2025, 2160, 2400, 2592, 2700, 3240,
3600, 4050, 4320, 5400, 6480, 7200, 8100, 10800, 12960, 16200, 21600, 32400, 64800

DIVISORES COMUNES

1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 12, 24

Parece bastante difícil hacer que las dos premisas que he enunciado se cumplan al mismo tiempo...

Comment: Simplemente no se puede resolver. Cual es el objetivo de solucionar estas ecuaciones?

Comment: Necesitaría resolverlas para crear una matriz de comprobación de paridad de un código SC-LDPC, con unos valorea prefijados para el tamaño del mensaje y el de la palabra código. ¡Gracias por responder!

Comment: Creo que es muy dificil que alguien te responda. Puedes contextualizar la pregunta editandola?. Di que quieres resolver las matrices para el método sc-ldpc y menciona de qué área de estudio es, también explica lo que sepas hasta el momento sobre como funcionan y pon un título de acuerdo al tema. Mira este documento https://link.springer.com/article/10.1186/s13634-016-0311-9 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rQnJtmdFwBQ Intentaré ayudarte, pero hay muy poca información al respecto :(

Comment: http://www.mdpi.com/1099-4300/18/8/305/pdf